# python worm how to make it more complex?

Tags: python

Please be kind this is my second post and i hope you all like.
Here I have made a program that makes directories inside directories,
 but the problem is I would like a way to make it self replicate.
Any ideas and help is greatly appreciated.

Before:

```
user/scripts
```

After:

```
user/scripts/worm1/worm2/worm3
```

The script is as follows:

```
import os, sys, string, random
worms_made = 0
stop = 20
patha = ''
pathb = '/'
pathc = ''
def fileworm(worms_made, stop, patha, pathb, pathc):
    filename = (''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase 
    +string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for i in range(8)))
    pathc = patha + filename + pathb
    worms_made = worms_made + 1
    os.system("mkdir %s" % filename)
    os.chdir(pathc)
    print "Worms made: %r" % worms_made
    if worms_made == stop:
        print "*Done"
        exit(0)
    elif worms_made != stop:
        pass  
    fileworm(worms_made, stop, patha, pathb, pathc)

fileworm(worms_made, stop, patha, pathb, pathc)
```

Comment: It would help if you edited the question to explain more about how you are trying to make the directories. Give an example directory structure, i.e. before and after after of what the code is trying to do.

Comment: I shall do so now thank you for the honest feedback it does help.

Comment: Take a look at [`os.path.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=makedirs#os.makedirs). This would let you create your `after` structure with a single Python call.

Comment: Thank you @MartinEvans that should make this code more simplistic for me to make more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a variable depth, you could do something like this:

```
import os

depth = 3
worms = ['worm{}'.format(x) for x in range(1, depth+1)]
path = os.path.join(r'/user/scripts', *worms)
os.path.makedirs(path)
```

As mentioned, [`os.path.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=makedirs#os.makedirs) will create all the required folders in one call. You just need to build the full path.

Python has a function to help with creating paths called `os.path.join()`. This makes sure the correct `/` or `\` is automatically added for the current operating system between each part.

`worms` is a list containing `["worm1", "worm2", "worm3"]`, it is created using a Python feature called a list comprehension. This is passed to the `os.path.join()` function using `*` meaning the each element of the list is passed as a separate parameter.

I suggest you try adding `print worms` or `print path` to see how it works.

The result is that a string looking something like as follows is passed to the function to create your folder structure:

```
/user/scripts/worm1/worm2/worm3
```

Comment: very good answer and should solve the issue I have encountered.